# Python interpreter crashes while using pygame.mixer.music.load(filename)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to play .mp3 files using pygame. 
But pygame.mixer.music.load("A.mp3") is causing my interpreter to crash. My .py file and .mp3 files are in the same folder. I have also tried specifying the full path for the mp3 file.
Someone please help. I am using anaconda.
Here is my code for reference.

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Memes.')


pygame.mixer.music.load("A.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(2)
pygame.mixer.music.stop()

while True: # Main Loop

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

[Crash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAvaI.png)

Comment: could you please edit you question and give the crash dialog?

Comment: Also, what interpreter are you using? Thanks!